# SOQL limits in andFinally TriggerHandler

Tags: field-update, triggercontext, bulk, trigger

1)Is it a good idea to keep a list or map of ids of the affected records and passing to gateway class method called in andFinally which runs a SOQL if necessary (like for child records)?

2)If this is fine, what is the purpose of bulkAfter and bulkBefore, what is the best design pattern to follow for bulk triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. But better to pass the list of eligible records to the getaway class method and then make a set of its ids for further usage.

2) From the docs:

> All triggers are bulk triggers by default, and can process multiple
>   records at a time. You should always plan on processing more than one
>   record at a time.

You should check the entry rule criteria for an operation in trigger and prepare a list of records to be processed and then pass it to the getaway class methods.

```
trigger TriggerName on sObject (before insert)
{
  if(trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert)
  {
    List<sObject> objList = new List<sObject>();
    for(sObject obj : Trigger.new)
    {
      if(/*your entry criteria*/)
      {
         objList.add(obj);
      }
    }
    if(!objList.isEmpty())
      MyGetAwayClass.myMethod(objList);
  }
}
```

And then you can process the records in the myMethod function and can add errors as well if needed on the items of objList.

This is a pretty decent format for any triggers, keeping only the highest level check on the trigger and passing the items for further processing in getaway class.

Comment: Santanu, thanks for the answer. so does that mean, I will not be hitting governer limits in the gateway class. and this question is related to this pattern http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers where there is already bulk methods available.